# Wine from Tropical Fruit

Tags: wine, fruit

I am looking for recipes/suggestions for making wine with tropical fruit. I am particularly interested in mango as I have lots of mango trees here (Nicaragua). I would also be interested in papaya, guava and guava-banana.

Comment: Why stop at wine?  Use it for beer, wine, spirits, anything!  Sounds pretty tasty.

Answer (score 3):

Banana is higher in sugar content followed by mango, papaya and then guava. Typically people add sugar in with the fruit to increase the specific gravity. This gives you more alcohol content in the final product. You may not have to add as much extra sugar if you mix the other fruits with bananas. Aim for something around 1.080 S.G. to start with.

Pay close attention to the acid balance in the must. That is the most important measurement next to the gravity. The fruit you mentioned is not particularly acidic so you may need adjust it higher. A simple acid test will help you decide. You can change the acid balance by adding citric acid. Adding lime, lemon or orange juice will do the trick. If the acid is too high add water, but not too much water or you lose the flavor.

With all fruit wine you should add pectic enzyme. This breaks down the pectin in fruit and makes the liquid less 'thick' and helps it clear. It's not strictly necessary but I found it to be noticeable in the finished wine.

Use a white wine or champagne yeast.

I have not made the guava recipe from [this site](http://www.honeycreek.us/recipe.php) but the cranberry wine is very good. And they have other general wine making advise as well.

Let us know how you get on!